# Reading STDOUT from Shell Script (EASY)

Tags: shell, stdout

I'm sure this is SUPER easy.  I am trying to read a string from STDOUT.  I submit a job onto another machine and then I WANT to be able to send "bjobs" which checks if the job has been finished. I want to be able to read STDOUT and detect when it has finished then move on.

This is what I have and it isn't working but I feel super close!

### Waiting for stdout to read "No unfinished job found"

```
bjobs
IFS= read -r line
echo "$line"
while "$line" != "No unfinished job found"
do
echo "$line"
sleep 30s
bjobs
IFS= read -r line
done
```

any help would be appreciated! This is one of my first shell scripts

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you are missing is that `read` will read from its stdin ... not its stdout.  So you have to arrange that its stdin is corresponds to the stdout of the command that you want it to read.  The straight-forward way to do that is to use a pipe (`|`)

For example:

```
    $ bjobs | ( IFS= ; read -r line ; echo "$line" ; while "$line" != "No unfinished job found" ; do ; echo "$line" ; sleep 30s ; read -r line ; done )
```

The `(` ... `)` is creating a subshell ...